# Is there any typing option in android spinner?

Tags: android-spinner

[image: Microsoft word drop-down image]

As shown in the image, in Microsoft Word/Powerpoint the drop-down spinner of font size enables the users to type his own choice of font size in the spinner box in addition to manually selecting one from the drop-down list.
My question is if it is possible in Android to get the "self-typing" option likewise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. I've solved it this way.

```
<FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@android:color/background_light">
  <Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"></Spinner>
  <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:text="12"
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:gravity="center"/>
</FrameLayout>
```